# Renaming a table where only part of the table name is known

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm working on some tools to facilitate importing a lot of data and cleaning it up before appending to another table.

As part of this procedure I need to rename an imported table before the rest of my processes.

```
Private Sub btnRenameTable_Click()
    DoCmd.Rename "NEW_DATA", acTable, "DATA SOURCE"
End Sub
```

The problem I have is the table to be renamed has a variance in the form of a number at the end i.e. `DATA SOURCE 01`, `DATA SOURCE 02`, etc.

How can I modify the above code to find the table and rename it without having to modify the original name every time?  I just need it to check for "DATA SOURCE" in the table title, the numbers are irrelevant to my needs.

Comment: To get the name you need to look at the table MSysObjects. Then you can issue your Rename command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `Like` operator to find the renamed table.  Posting an example, you can easily modify it to your use (contains example of the `Like` operator and using an index to rename all your new tables in one go instead of having to spam click a button)

```
Dim td As TableDef
Dim i as Long
i = 1
For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If td.Name Like "NEW SOURCE*" Then
        DoCmd.Rename "NEW SOURCE", acTable, "DATA SOURCE" & Format(i,"00")
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you this worked as intended and offers flexibility for batches if required.